# Email Validation... advocating the use of +, and how embarrassed would you be to have written this?

Tags: javascript, email-validation

I take full advantage of GMail's wildcard feature (username+wildcard@gmail.com).  Unfortunately it seems that most developers don't understand that `+` is valid in an email address.  This makes trying to unsubscribe a real chore sometimes.

Take [TicketMaster](http://email.livenationent.com/ln40/imgs/LNPD/1/93/1/WOP/WOP.php?bi=2934870177&em=user+wildcard@gmail.com&cid=49359567&t=N) for example... immediately you notice that they didn't even bother escaping the email address, so the text field defaults to "user wilcard@gmail.com".  Not a problem, we can just add the `+` manually.  Once Submit is clicked, you'll notice the validation stops you right in your tracks.  What now?

Most users would have to further contact TicketMaster and attempt to explain the situation.  I opened up FireBug to investigate.  That's when I noticed this whopping **74 line** email validation function with so much redundancy it's ridiculous.  My favorite check is on line 20, informing the user that his/her email `cannot have more than one @`.  Unreal.  My second favorite part is the TWO regular expressions used!

Imagine... someone was paid money for this... and by the looks of it, they were paid by the line count.

```
//Validates the email
function validateOptoutEmail(object) {
    var emailStr = object.value;
    if(emailStr == '' || emailStr == null) {
        alert('Email can not be empty. Please provide email');
        object.value = '';
        object.focus();
        return false;
    } else if(Trim(emailStr).length == 0) {
        alert('Email can not be empty. Please provide email');
        object.value = '';
        object.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        var atcount=0;
        for(var i=0;i<emailStr.length;i++) {
            if(emailStr.charAt(i)=='@') atcount++;
        }
        if(atcount>1) {
            alert('Invalid email. Email cannot have more than one @');
            object.value = '';
            object.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(emailStr.indexOf('.') == -1) {
            alert('Invalid email. Email must have one dot');
            object.value = '';
            object.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if(emailStr.indexOf('..')!= -1) {
            alert('Invalid email. Email cannot have consecutive dots');
            object.value = '';
            object.focus();
            return false;
        }
        var dotpos=0;
        for(var i=dotpos;i< emailStr.length;i++) {
            var ichar=emailStr.charAt(i);
            if(ichar=='.') dotpos=i;
        }
        for(var i=dotpos+1;i< emailStr.length;i++) {
            var ichar=emailStr.charAt(i);
            if((!isNaN(ichar)) || (ichar == '_')) {
                alert('Invalid email. Email cannot have numbers or _ after dot');
                object.value = '';
                object.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
        var pattern2=/^([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;
        var pattern1=/^[0-9a-zA-Z\-\_.]+@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;
        if (pattern1.test(emailStr)) {
            if(pattern2.test(emailStr)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                alert('Invalid email');
                object.value = '';
                object.focus();
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('Invalid email');
            object.value = '';
            object.focus();
            return false;
        }
        alert('Invalid email');
        object.value = '';
        object.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I eventually just put a break point in FireBug and changed the value of the email address passed into the validation function.  From there everything worked fine...

All that said, **how can we get the word out there that `+` is valid in an email address?**  Too often, I'm unable to use the email address that I want to use for certain web sites because developers simply aren't aware of what constitutes a valid email address.

Comment: "Folly, thou conquerest, and I must yield! Against stupidity the very gods Themselves contend in vain."  -- Friedrich Schiller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point them at the rfc:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#page-10

3.2.3 states "+" is a valid atom